# Popular select de forma dinamica

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma consulta que retorna um `array` onde eu quero popular um `select` de forma dinâmica, mas pelo código abaixo ele da com **undefined**

```
for(var i = 0; i <= cidades.length; i++){
            var html = "";
            html += "<option>" + cidades[i] + "</option>";    
            document.getElementById("cidade").append(html);
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu for está percorrendo uma vez a mais, e também acredito que o método `append` não vá funcionar em elementos do tipo select, tente modificar o `innerHTML` dele.

> Segue abaixo um exemplo:

```
for(var i = 0; i < cidades.length; i++)
{
    var html = '<option>'+cidades[i]+'</option>';
    document.getElementById('cidade').innerHTML += html;
}
```

> Outra maneira legal de percorrer o vetor é usando o forEach, segue exemplo:

```
cidades.forEach(function (cidade) {
    var html = '<option>'+cidade+'</option>';
    document.getElementById('cidade').innerHTML += html;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

O elemento "cidade" é um `select` por isso e adicionar `html` a ele como faria num elemento `div` talvez não seja a melhor opção, a criar os elementos `option` e adicionar seria mais legível:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= cidades.length; i++){
    var selectCidade = document.getElementById("cidade");
    var option   = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = cidades[i];
    option.text  = cidades[i];
    selectCidade.appendChild(option);
}
```